# how to capture mouseclick in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I capture the position of a mouseclick from the user in my Flash window using Actionscript 3.0?

Answer (score 3):

Ron DeVera is close, but I wouldn't use an inline function, and the object passed to the function is not Event, but MouseEvent.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onStageMouseDown);

function _onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e);
}

//traces
//[MouseEvent type="click" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 localX=96 localY=96 stageX=96 stageY=96 relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=false delta=0]
```

All of the properties in the output above are available through the object that gets passed to the Event Listener Method, _onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent);  Hence the following

```
function _onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e.localX);
    trace(e.stageX);
    //Note that the above two traces are identical as we are listening to the stage for our MouseEvent.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good catch, Brian! I agree with your answer, and have removed mine to reduce clutter.

To be honest, I also never use inline handlers in my own real-world AS3 code, but only when giving simple examples. I should really practice preaching what I practice. :)

Comment: Also you can obtain mouse position outside the mouse listener functions using **stage.mouseX & stage.mouseY**

Answer (score 1):

They explained it well, but here's the full code to illustrate it a little more for you:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event: MouseEvent) : void
{
    // these are the x and y relative to the object
    var localMouseX: Number = event.localX;
    var localMouseY: Number = event.localY;

    // these are the x and y relative to the whole stage
    var stageMouseX: Number = event.stageX;
    var stageMouseY: Number = event.stageY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Location defined by what context? The whole page? One or more specific clickable controls?

Answer (score 0):

You may query any DisplayObject's mouseX and mouseY whenever you like.