# How to detect position of the click?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to make an object move to the position of a click 
how can i do that?

I only want to know how to detect the x-coordinates and y-coordinates of the click  ?

Comment: Show some minimum code. Easier to show the fix that way. Anyways you want something like `stage.mouseX;` and `stage.mouseY;`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to capture mouseclick in actionscript 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710792/how-to-capture-mouseclick-in-actionscript-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onStageMouseDown);
function _onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e.localX);
    trace(e.stageX);
}

//output
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mouseEvent.stageX`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#stageX),
[`mouseEvent.stageY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#stageY)
or
[`mouseEvent.localX`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#localX),
[`mouseEvent.localY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#localY)
or
[`mouseX`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mouseX), [`mouseY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mouseY) of any `DisplayObject` (including `Stage`)